# Inconsistent field separator behaviour of space in awk

Tags: awk

The following awk script shows how a leading space `' '` is ignored as a field separator, but other characters are treated as a separator with a preceding null $1 field.

Is there some way to make this behaviour consistent for all values of the field separator?

```
echo -e " Data\tdlm\t\$1\t\$2\t\$3"  
for d in '^' ':' '"' 'x' '/' ' ' ;do
  echo "${d}1${d}2${d}" |awk -F"$d" '
       { printf "|%s|\t|%s|\t|%s|\t|%s|\t|%s|\n", $0, FS, $1, $2, $3; }'
done
```

The output:

```
 Data   dlm     $1      $2      $3
|^1^2^| |^|     ||      |1|     |2|
|:1:2:| |:|     ||      |1|     |2|
|"1"2"| |"|     ||      |1|     |2|
|x1x2x| |x|     ||      |1|     |2|
|/1/2/| |/|     ||      |1|     |2|
| 1 2 | | |     |1|     |2|     ||
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set FS to be a regexp, `FS = "[ \t]+"` (which is 'whitespace'), and it will no longer strip leading and trailing spaces.  awk only strips leading and trailing whitespace when `FS=" "`.

I don't think it's possible to tell awk not to do it, when `FS=" "`.

Comment: It works with `awk -F"[ ]" so that gets me most of the way there.. and I at least understand what's going on now.. thanks.. So it seems to be the same story as for any regex: *beware of the stray regex special chars*... (+1) I'll wait a time before accepting the answer, as perhaps(?) there is a non-regex way to disable the stripping .. IFS has no effect in awk.

Comment: It's looking pretty definite: [Using Regular Expressions to Separate Fields](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Field-Splitting)... Thanks

Comment: It's even specified this way by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_04): “If `FS` is `<space>`, skip leading and trailing `<blank>`s; fields shall be delimited by sets of one or more `<blank>`s” [otherwise behave intuitively].